# Disable PrimeNG Calendar month selection in Typescript

Tags: typescript, calendar, angular7, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using PrimeNg Calendar in my angular 7 project, wanted to disable month navigator on some conditions at the component level.
 Ex: Current Month is February, I want to disable month navigator after the march month.

[image]

Using *:host and ::ng-deep* I can override Primeng styles in CSS file

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-next{  
 display:none;

}
```

But I want to do the changing styles in the component. Tried below code, but not working

```
   let datePickerNext = document.querySelectorAll('.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev');
datePickerNext.forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute("style", " margin-top: 0.6em;opacity: 0.2;");
});
```

Any ideas to achieve this

Comment: have you used [maxDate]="maxDateValue"  property?

Comment: [maxdate] disabled dates beyond that. here i need to disable Month Navigators(< ,>)

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever come up with a solution? I had a similar use case on a project, and someone on my team came up with this. It appears to work on Chrome/Edge. In your TypeScript, simply apply either or both classes on the p-calendar (ui-datepicker-prev-disable or ui-datepicker-next-disable).

```
:host ::ng-deep p-calendar.ui-datepicker-next-disable .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-next {
  color: #dddddd !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

:host ::ng-deep p-calendar.ui-datepicker-prev-disable .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev {
  color: #dddddd !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I also added an event handler for onMonthChange just in case anyone managed to re-enable the icons.

In the HTML template I added this binding. minMonth and maxMonth are variables set in ngOnInit and are based on the minimumDate and maximumDate.

```
<p-calendar #calendar
   [ngClass]="{
     'ui-datepicker-prev-disable': calendar.currentMonth === minMonth, 
      'ui-datepicker-next-disable': calendar.currentMonth === maxMonth}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be achieved either by hiding or blurring the navigation arrows.
Need to use onMonthChange, pass the event, based on event apply the CSS changes to hide navigation arrow.
[image]

Below is the code:

HTML:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date4" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" 
    [readonlyInput]="true" inputId="min-max" 
    (onMonthChange)="disableDatePickerPrev($event)"
    [ngClass]="{'disable-datepicker-prev': disabled}">
</p-calendar>
```

Here onMonthChange has been used, created a function which will pass the event to apply the CSS dynamically.

Typescript:

```
disabled:boolean = false;
disableDatePickerPrev(evt){
    // current month december =12
    // disable prev month navigation for october =10
    // can set month value dynamically
    if(evt.month <= 10) this.disabled=true;
}
```

CSS:

```
p-calendar.disable-datepicker-prev ::ng-deep .p-datepicker-prev {
    display: none;
}
```